# Compute execution time of membership search of generator in python

Tags: python, time, generator, python-itertools

I'm currently working with generators and factorials in python. 
As an example:
`itertools.permutations(range(100))`
Meaning, I receive a **generator object containing 100!** values.

In reality, this code does look a bit more complicated; I'm using a list of sublists instead of range(100), with the goal to find a combination of those sublists meeting my conditions.

This is the code:

```
mylist = [[0, 0, 1], ..., [5, 7, 3]] # random numbers
x = True in (combination for combination in itertools.permutations(mylist) 
             if compare(combination))
# Compare() does return True for one or a few combination in that generator
```

I realized this is very time-consuming. Is there a **more efficient** way to do this, and, moreover, a way to **compute how many time** it is going to take?

I've done a few %timeit using ipython:

```
%timeit (combination for combination in itertools.permutations(mylist) if compare(combination))
 --> 697 ns

%timeit (combination for combination in itertools.permutations(range(100)) if compare(combination))
 --> 572 ns
```

**Note:** I do understand that the generator is just being created, when it's "consumed", meaning the genertor comprehension needs to be executed at first, to start the creaton of itself at all.

I've seen a lot of tutorials explaining how generators do work, but I've found nothing about the execution time.
Moreover I don't need an exact value, like timing the execution time using time-module in my program, hence I need a rough value *before* execution.

**Edit:**
I've also tested this for a **smaller amount of values**, for a list containing 24 sublists, 10 sublists and 5 sublists. Doing this, I receive an **instant output**. 
*This means, the program does work, it is just a matter of time.*

My problem is (said more clarified): **How much time** is this going to take, and: Is there a **less time consuming way** to do it?

Comment: 1) Isn't the generator returning a list of `combination`s? Why would any of them be `True`, shouldn't that be the value returned from `compare`? 2) `True in` says there is *at least* one combination that returns true, not *exactly* one. Is that your goal?

Comment: @rassar 1) Compare sums up the first element in each sublist and compares it to a predetermined integer. It does return True if it is True and False if it isn't.

Comment: 2) Yes, it is ok if there is at least one value True in the generator comprehension.

Comment: What you are timing is just the creation of the generator, not its execution.  `list(itertools ...)` runs it.  A simple example would be `range(5)` versus `list(range(5))`.  `(x for x in range(5)` is a generator expression.  `[x for x in range(5)]` produces the actual list.

Comment: @hpaulj Thank you, does this mean timing list(_operator containing five elements_)) is about the same to timing x = True in (_operator containing five elements_), related to the execution time?

Comment: This strongly depends on what the data is and on what `compare` does. Pretty much impossible to answer without knowing those things.

Comment: It does just compare if the value is True, and the range of values is True and False, @Heap Overflow

Comment: Huh? You don't give it boolean values, you give it permutations of lists of numbers.

Comment: Yes, it compares lists of numbers, but passes them to a function, which is then returning True or False.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A comparison of generators, generator expression, lists and list comprehensions:

```
In [182]: range(5)                                                                             
Out[182]: range(0, 5)
In [183]: list(range(5))                                                                       
Out[183]: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
In [184]: (x for x in range(5))                                                                
Out[184]: <generator object <genexpr> at 0x7fc18cd88a98>
In [186]: [x for x in range(5)]                                                                
Out[186]: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Some timings:

```
In [187]: timeit range(1000)                                                                   
248 ns ± 2.79 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
In [188]: timeit (x for x in range(1000))                                                      
802 ns ± 6.97 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
In [189]: timeit [x for x in range(1000)]                                                      
43.4 µs ± 27.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
In [190]: timeit list(range(1000))                                                             
23.6 µs ± 1.03 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

time for setting up a generator is (practically) independent of the parameter.  Populating the list scales roughly with the size.

```
In [193]: timeit range(100000)                                                                 
252 ns ± 1.57 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
In [194]: timeit list(range(100000))                                                           
4.41 ms ± 103 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

## edit

Timings show that a `in` test on a generator is somewhat faster than a `list`, but it still scales with the `len`:

```
In [264]: timeit True in  (True for x in itertools.permutations(range(15),2) if x==(14,4))     
17.1 µs ± 17.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
In [265]: timeit list (True for x in itertools.permutations(range(15),2) if x==(14,4))         
18.5 µs ± 158 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
In [266]: timeit (14,4) in itertools.permutations(range(15),2)                                 
8.85 µs ± 8.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
In [267]: timeit list(itertools.permutations(range(15),2))                                     
11.3 µs ± 21.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Comment: Okay, and do you think converting a generator to a list is roughly equal to doing a membership search on it?

Comment: My timings show that a `in` test is somewhat faster, but it still scales with the range.

Comment: If you just want to measure the iteration, try `deque(iterable, 0)` instead of `list(iterable)`.

Comment: Thank you for the edit, I didn't know one could perform a membership search as a timeit statement. I've also tried deque, worked for me. I will do a series of tests to get an overview of how long the resqective operations might take.